# Problems with fit_transform/transform in category_encoder

Tags: python, data-science

I encountered such a problem when transforming the OrdinalEncoder I get an error
It says that my cols does not list all the columns I need for X_train
I hope to get your help.
I tried to submit my code to the Kaggle contest, but I got an error.
In Jupyter everything works

```
import category_encoders as ce
encoder = ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols = [['MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl','Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir','Electrical', 'KitchenQual', 'Functional', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond','PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition']])

X_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)
```

and error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
**# # /tmp/ipykernel_27/3436411182.py in \<module\>**
1 X_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
2 X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)
**# # /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, \*\*fit_params)**
850         if y is None:
851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
852             return self.fit(X, \*\*fit_params).transform(X)
853         else:
854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
**# # /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/category_encoders/utils.py in fit(self, X, y, \*\*kwargs)**
297         self.\_determine_fit_columns(X)
298
299         if not set(self.cols).issubset(X.columns):
300             raise ValueError('X does not contain the columns listed in cols')
301
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

See, I changed the double square brackets to single square and regular round brackets, but it gives me an error that (X does not contain the columns listed in cols), although everything matches in columns. I have checked many times

```
encoder = ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols = [('MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 
                                    'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl',
                                    'Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual',
                                    'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir',
                                    'Electrical', 'KitchenQual', 'Functional', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond',
                                    'PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition')])


ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/3436411182.py in <module>
----> 1 X_train = encoder.fit_transform(X_train)
      2 X_test = encoder.transform(X_test)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    850         if y is None:
    851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 852             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    853         else:
    854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/category_encoders/utils.py in fit(self, X, y, **kwargs)
    298 
    299         if not set(self.cols).issubset(X.columns):
--> 300  raise ValueError('X does not contain the columns listed in cols')
    301 
    302         if self.handle_missing == 'error':

ValueError: X does not contain the columns listed in cols
```

If anything, I'm a newbie, so don't swear.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have list in list for cols argument. Use this instead -
`encoder = ce.OrdinalEncoder(cols = ['MSZoning', 'Street', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Neighborhood', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle', 'RoofMatl','Exterior1st', 'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'Foundation', 'BsmtQual','BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'Heating', 'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir','Electrical', 'KitchenQual', 'Functional', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond','PavedDrive', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition'])`

Comment: I originally had single brackets, but I still got the error. Error: unhashable type: 'Series'